# PHP: ArrayObject method signature not compatible with ArrayAccess interface

Tags: php, arrays, spl, psalm-php

When I extend an `ArrayObject` and use [vimeo/psalm](https://github.com/vimeo/psalm) static analyzer to check my code, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: ParamNameMismatch
at /var/www/file.php:13:37
Argument 1 of ControllerDescriptionArray::offsetSet has wrong name $key, expecting $offset as defined by ArrayAccess::offsetSet (see https://psalm.dev/230)
    public function offsetSet(mixed $key, mixed $value): void {
```

This is the file in question:

```php
class ControllerDescriptionArray extends \ArrayObject {
    public function offsetSet(mixed $key, mixed $value): void {
        if ($value instanceof ControllerDescription === false) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Value must be a ControllerDescription');
        }
        parent::offsetSet($key, $value);
    }
```

No runtime errors happen, only Psalm is not happy. Anybody knows something about it?

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetset.php, the `ArrayObject::offsetSet()` method signature is:

```php
public ArrayObject::offsetSet(mixed $key, mixed $value): void
```

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/arrayaccess.offsetset.php, the `ArrayAccess::offsetSet()` method signature is:

```php
public ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not certain if there's a way to make Psalm happy in this scenario: https://psalm.dev/r/a1325749cb

Comment: But by my understanding of the RFC along with a test, I think your code is correct. If a child class overrides a parent class and changes the parameter names, the child class wins: https://3v4l.org/YPQM6

Comment: @ChrisHaas that's the weird thing, I do not change parameter names. ArrayObject does. IMHO ArrayObject should use the parameter names as specified in the ArrayAccess interface.

Comment: My point was that if you had to pick ArrayObject or ArrayAccess to follow for naming, you did it right from the engine’s perspective. I think Psalm needs an exception to their logic for this. I also hunted through core’s source and mailing lists, and didn’t see anyone specifically talking about this, so maybe a bug/change could be filed by someone